# FFT of a variable-frequency signal

Tags: fft

I'm writing a software that read engine rpm during acceleration, using a recorded audio.
To do that, I divide the record in small time-steps, and for each one I do an FFT, to know the rpm in that timesteps.
Because, in the time-steps, the rpm is not constant, but vary from minimum to maximum (because of the acceleration), I'm doing some test using a pure sine wave with frequency varying from 300 to 545 rad/s (48 to 87 Hz) in 4s time.
In the real audio, I take a time-step of about 0.5s, but now I'm studying what happen with longer time-step to understand how FFT works in variable-frequency audio.

This is the FFT of that signal:

[image]

As you can see, the two peaks are at 52 and 125 Hz. Now, I'm wondering why there is 125Hz... I tought I will found more or less two peak at 50-90 Hz.
So, why? And how can I estimate the frequency range during an acceleration?

Comment: The 'peaks' at the edges of the transform look like the 'Gibbs' phenomenon, but could be due to aliasing so make sure that max frequency $\nu_m$ and step time $\Delta t $ follow $\nu_m \le 1/(2\Delta t)$